# In how many ways can $4$ people, $2$ men and $2$ women, be selected from a set of $5$ twins if each person is selected from a different set of twins?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In how many ways can $4$ people, $2$ men and $2$ women, be selected from a set of $5$ twins, each of which is composed of one man and one woman, if each person is selected from a different set of twins?

What I was able to get thru was basically, there will be $5$ men and $5$ women. Which means that if we select $2$ men and $2$ women from these people we will get $10 \cdot 10 = 100$ ways. But, in this case, we have pairs that are not from distinct pairs of twins. I am having trouble in finding people from different pairs of twins.

Comment: Are you saying that we must select each person from a different pair of twins?

Comment: Also, your title is misleading.  We are not interested in the number of distinct people.  Rather, we are interested in the number of ways we can select groups of two men and two women from the five sets of twins with the restriction, if I understand the question correctly, that each person is selected from a different pair of twins.

Comment: it's not hard ... what's got you stuck again ?

Comment: Yup. I really do not know how to proceed in this questions. Some clues please

Comment: Yup, i think you are correct N.F.

Comment: But how does one calculate people from different pair of twins ?

Answer (score 1):

**Strategy:**

1. Select from which two of the five pairs of twins the two women are selected.  Since there is only one woman in each pair of twins, doing so completely determines which two women are selected.
2. From the remaining three pairs of twins, select two pairs of twins from which the two men are selected.  Since there is only one man in each pair of twins, doing so completely determines which two men are selected.

Comment: Mathematically, we select women from 5 pair of twins, in 5C2, which is 10 ways. Next, in order to emphasize on 'different'. We choose 2 men from remaining other pair which is 3C2 which is 3. So, answer is 3 * 10 = 30 ? I do not know if I am right. Thanks for help N.F. Taussig!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.